# Converting Boundfield to hyperlink with if statement

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding, hyperlink

I've been stuck on this for a little while now and can't find any answers that are specific enough to help with my problem. 
I have a grid that is bound, containing notes automatically generated for different members of our crm system. Some notes contain PDFs - (non-clickable that you have to copy and paste into another tab on the web browser to open), others do not and are just general notes. I need to be able to convert the note to a hyperlink IF the note contains a link. 
So far, I have managed to get all of the notes to come up as clickable links however I really need the IF statement in there as well. I am a complete novice and so please excuse any small issues that do not impact this issue directly.

```asp
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="100px">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPDF" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Ir" PostBackUrl='<%# "~/" + Eval("Note") %>' Text="Link to Voucher"></asp:LinkButton>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Have you tried the Visible property and use an Eval to set it up?

Comment: Why don't you use conditional operators?

Answer (score 0):

So, you can achieve this behavior. I assume you are simply just asking for a conditional thing to populate the `LinkButtons` with url or leave them with the text only. I will now write the solution with different possibilities according to my understanding:

**Method 1**
So, with this way you can check if your bound `DataTable` has null values and if it has, you can simply return an empty string to the `PostBackUrl` property.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPDF" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Ir" PostBackUrl='<%#  Eval("Notes") == DBNull.Value ? "" : "~/" + Eval("Note") %>' Text="Link to Voucher"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Note: If you use this method you will still have a postback. And the links that were not fetched or were null the will still have respective anchor elements on the web pages that will take you nowhere.

**Method 2** 
With this way you can tweak with `Visible` property of the element. by this way you will actually have `LinkButton` Controls that were not `DBNulls`

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPDF" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Ir" Visible='<%# Eval("Notes") != DBNull.Value %>' PostBackUrl='<%#  Eval("Notes") == DBNull.Value ? "" : "~/" + Eval("Note") %>' Text="Link to Voucher"></asp:LinkButton>
```

**Method 3** 
I will recommend using this one if you are not strict on having a server control and you want to have the 'Link to voucher' displayed on screen and you are not catching this control in your codebehind in `OnRowCommand` event.

```
<a href='<%# Eval("Notes") == DBNull.Value ? "javascript:void(0)" : "~/" + Eval("Notes") %>'>Link to voucher</a>
```

Reason: Simple and straight forward.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Can I ask you to clarify the last method you've posted though? When I copy and paste the code into Visual Studio, the javascript is erroring (I don't know Javascript at all yet, just standard code) and I would rather learn what it means rather than using code I don't understand to fix a problem! Thanks :)